# {"result":560,"type":"exception"} response for axs request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, mendix

I encounter {"result":560,"type":"exception"} response for axs request in jmeter while designing a script to do a load test for a mendix web application. First I encountered untheorized response on login so i used reg. expression extractor to extract CSRF-TOKEN and then login worked fine. after login and try to submit an application, i got {"result":560,"type":"exception"} response. what might be the issue and how can it be solved?

[Response body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PS2W.png)

[Response header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAyrp.png)

[Request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxr0I.png)

[Request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W7wq.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're sending an incorrect request. Unfortunately we cannot state what exactly is wrong because we need to see both:

1. Reference successful request including URL, [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) and body from i.e. real browser
2. The request from JMeter which fails including URL, headers and body

So I can only suggest to use a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the requests from the real browser and JMeter and compare them. Request must be exactly the same (apart from dynamic parameters which need to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/)). Given you send the same request as browser does you should get the same (successful) response

Other things to consider:

- Check your server log, it might be the case you will figure out the reason from there like it was in [this forum thread](https://forum.mendix.com/link/questions/3638)
- Given you have Arabic characters in the request body ensure to use proper [encoding](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding), i.e. [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is always a good choice